# When to make child tables for master tables

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a master table with around 30 columns. I have a new requirement where in i need to store 4 new fields against a master ID. This data will not be there for all master records. So i am confused to make a child table or better store in master table only? Any help on this?

Comment: Isn't there any way to create Many to Many or Many to One relational structure? What content in columns?

Comment: If you will have one record for one msterid then you should add these columns in master table

Answer (score 0):

In general you question is **"Which is better - store a lot of NULL-s or make a lot of JOINS?"**

You own the database so You should decide based on you database structure and queries having in mind [Normalization](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) strategies. Test both cases and decide.

Comment: I dont know your database strucute so could use classical way - many to many relation and JOINS.